# Start Process With Logged On User Credentials Windows 7

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, process.start

I have a deployment package that opens an application when the instalation has finished.
On opening, this application validates a connection to a database using Integrated windows security.

The Problem is that when it calls

```
Process.Start(XXXXXXXXXX)
```

The application is opened under the machine account, the one that actualy does the install under UAC in Windows 7.

I know i can use the ProcessStartInfo object to ask the user to specify their password etc however this will be really annoying for them when they are already logged onto the machine.

I have tried using ProcessStartInfo, WinAPI etc but to no avail.

Has anyone else encountered this type of issue and/or have a suggested solution.

In summary I am trying to call

```
Process.Start........
```

Under the credentials of the logged on user as the last action of an deployment package under Windows 7

VB.NET application developed in VS2010 using Windows Installer Deployment.